# How did a Star Trek writer's name end up in The X-Files?

Tags: star-trek, behind-the-scenes, the-x-files

[**André Bormanis**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andr%C3%A9_Bormanis) is a television producer, screenwriter, and consultant who worked on several series of Star Trek.  He was the principal scientific consultant for *TNG*, *DS9*, and *Voyager*.  He also wrote episodes for *Voyager* and *Enterprise* and served as a producer for the latter.

When I was rewatching the Season 8 *X-Files* episode **"Via Negativa"**, I noticed a character by the name of **Dr. Andre Bormanis** (played by [Grant Heslov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grant_Heslov)):

[image]

The Bormanis character manufactures drugs for a cult leader.

It would be hard to believe that these identical names are a coincidence.  I have come across pieces of unofficial commentary that concur with this — for example:

> The name "Andre Bormanis" is almost certainly taken from Dr. Andre Bormanis, science consultant to the Star Trek films and television series and a consultant to The Planetary Society.

([Source](http://x-files.host.sk/injokes8.php))

But I'm looking for something official.

**Is this *X-Files* character named after the real-life Star Trek writer / consultant and, if so, why?**

Comment: Next question: does Grant Heslov look like the real Andre Bormanis?

Comment: I read 'X-Files' and 'Star Trek' in the one question and knew this had to be you @Praxis: +1

Comment: @N_Soong : You know me so well.  ;-)

Comment: Andre Bormanis' name pops up in the credits of many different shows, not just Star Trek, although I believe Star Trek was his first.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Yes; because Andre Bormanis was an old friend of the episode's writer.

From [an archived version of the X-files official website](http://web.archive.org/web/20020202050416/http://www.thexfiles.com/episodes/season8/8x07_research.html):

> Andre Bormanis was named after Writer Frank Spotnitz's childhood friend. Bormanis went on to become a science consultant for *Star Trek:Voyager* and *Star Trek: Deep Space Nine*.

I found this by Googling "Andre Bormanis X-files named after". The first hit was from [the Wikipedia page for the relevant episode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Via_Negativa_%28The_X-Files%29), which contains a reference to the archived page linked and quoted above.

Comment: Nice find.  The X-Files web site *used* to have a great episode databank.  :-)

Comment: This is an instance of [tuckerization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuckerization).  It's very common for writers to name bit characters after real people.

Comment: @zwol Curiously, [Anthony Horowitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthony_Horowitz) often seems to be used for this: an Antoine Horwitzer appears in Darren Shan's Demonata series, and a Horri Antowitz is mentioned in Eoin Colfer's Artemis Fowl series.